# Combination Sum III on Leetcode

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, slice

The leetcode question is:

> Find all possible combinations of k numbers that add up to a number n, given that only numbers from 1 to 9 can be used and each combination should be a unique set of numbers.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: k = 3, n = 7
>
> Output:
>
> [[1,2,4]]
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: k = 3, n = 9
>
> Output:
>
> [[1,2,6], [1,3,5], [2,3,4]]

I find a solution in Javascript

```
var combinationSum3 = function(k, n) {
  var result = [];
  search(1, [], k, n);
  return result;

  function search(from, prefix, k, n) {
    if (k === 0 && n === 0) return result.push(prefix);
    if (from > 9) return;
    prefix.push(from);
    search(from + 1, prefix.slice(0), k - 1, n - from);
    prefix.pop();
    search(from + 1, prefix.slice(0), k, n);
  }
};
```

I suppose the slice(0) method return a copy of the original array, so I try to replace prefix.slice(0) with prefix. However, the result I get is [ [ ] ]. What is the issue here?

Comment: @AnotherGeek I don't get your words. Under Chrome console, the result I get is [ [ ] ]. Nina's answer explains well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a problem with reference. If you use slice, you get a copy ot the array. If you use only `prefix`, then all later operation, like push or pop afflicts the array.

If you do not like to work with a copy, you could use concat, which give a new array as well, but with new item/s.

You code would look like this:

```js
var combinationSum3 = function (k, n) {
    var result = [];
    search(1, [], k, n);
    return result;

    function search(from, prefix, k, n) {
        if (k === 0 && n === 0) return result.push(prefix);
        if (from > 9) return;
        search(from + 1, prefix.concat(from), k - 1, n - from);
        search(from + 1, prefix, k, n);
    }
};

console.log(combinationSum3(3, 7));
console.log(combinationSum3(3, 9));
console.log(combinationSum3(4, 12));
```